# Git command to show which specific files are ignored by .gitignore

Tags: git, ignore

I am getting my feet wet with Git and have the following issue:

My project source tree:

```
/
|
+--src/
+----refs/
+----...
|
+--vendor/
+----...
```

I have code (currently MEF) in my vendor branch that I will compile there and then move the references into `/src/refs` which is where the project picks them up from.

My issue is that I have my `.gitignore` set to ignore `*.dll` and `*.pdb`.  I can do a `git add -f bar.dll` to force the addition of the ignored file which is ok, the problem is I can not figure out to list what files exist that are ignored.

I want to list the ignored files to make sure that I don't forget to add them.

I have read the man page on `git ls-files` and can not make it work. It seems to me that `git ls-files --exclude-standard -i` should do what I want.  What am I missing?

Comment: These days, you wouldn't use git-ls-files but rather 'git ls-files'

Comment: I plead with you to check [riyad's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1446609/10608) as correct since that is the only one that admits there's no _guaranteed_ way to do this using only git commands (including the `git clean` trick) as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/Thr4wn/myths_about_git_show_all_ignored_files). Also, I recommend against the "exclude-from" example in your summary since that factually doesn't pay attention to any .gitignore files. I ask this especially because this page is the top Google response.

Comment: Quick point on "Summary of what works": the "Git ls-files" man page explains that the "-i" means include excluded files for the ls output.  I had the same misunderstanding, until I read 'it slowly'. ;-)

Comment: I have `git config --global alias.ls ls-files --exclude-standard`, and that makes the answer to this question `git ls -i`.

Comment: @AlexanderBird You should update your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12080920/812919 for the benefit of future readers if possible.

Comment: Answers belong in **answers**, not in questions. Summarizing answers in the question means that voting, moderation, &c. on the answers themselves loses its value.

Comment: `git status --ignored` is the one I prefer: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---ignoredltmodegt

Comment: Qwertymk's answer is THE answer. `git check-ignore -v [PATH]`

Comment: @AlexanderBird Your github link (https://github.com/Thr4wn/myths_about_git_show_all_ignored_files) appears to be dead. I searched the user (who still exists) for `git` and `ignored`, but no dice. [No archive.org copy either](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://github.com/Thr4wn/myths_about_git_show_all_ignored_files). Realizing you added in 2012, do you recall what it said, give or take?

Comment: oh man, I do not remember now. And I don't know why it's not there anymore either. I guess I deleted it. Sorry.

Comment: Last time I tried checking this with `git clean -dfxn` but forgot the `n` and deleted all my ignored files. DO NOT DO THIS.

Answer (score 963, accepted):

Notes:

- xiaobai's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore/12080920#12080920) is simpler (git1.7.6+): `git status --ignored`
  (as detailed in "[Is there a way to tell git-status to ignore the effects of `.gitignore` files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994612/is-there-a-way-to-tell-git-status-to-ignore-the-effects-of-gitignore-files/12080857#12080857)")

---

Also interesting (mentioned in [qwertymk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465546/qwertymk)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26580088/6309)), you can also use the [**`git check-ignore -v`**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) command, at least on Unix (**doesn't work** in a CMD **Windows** session, but works in a Windows CMD git bash session)

```
git check-ignore -- *
git check-ignore -v -- *
```

The second one displays the actual rule of the `.gitignore` which makes a file to be ignored in your git repo.
On Unix, using "[What expands to all files in current directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690809/what-expands-to-all-files-in-current-directory-recursively)" and a bash4+:

```
git check-ignore **/*
```

(or a `find -exec` command)

Note: [https://stackoverflow.com/users/351947/Rafi B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351947/c) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore/467053?noredirect=1#comment105393217_467053) to **avoid the (risky) globstar**:

```
git check-ignore -v $(find . -type f -print)
```

Make sure to exclude the files from the `.git/` subfolder though.

[CervEd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507124/cerved) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore/467053#comment120476196_467053), to avoid `.git/`:

```
find . -not -path './.git/*' | git check-ignore --stdin
```

---

Original answer (2009)

```
git ls-files -i
```

should work, except [its source code](http://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg03245.html) indicates:

```
if (show_ignored && !exc_given) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: --ignored needs some exclude pattern\n",
                        argv[0]);
```

`exc_given`?

It turns out it needs one more parameter after the `-i` to actually list anything.

Try:

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-from=[Path_To_Your_Global].gitignore
```

(but that would only list your *cached* (non-ignored) object, with a filter, so that is not quite what you want)

---

Example:

```
$ cat .git/ignore
# ignore objects and archives, anywhere in the tree.
*.[oa]
$ cat Documentation/.gitignore
# ignore generated HTML files,
*.html
# except foo.html which is maintained by hand
!foo.html
$ git ls-files --ignored \
    --exclude='Documentation/*.[0-9]' \
    --exclude-from=.git/ignore \
    --exclude-per-directory=.gitignore
```

---

Actually, in my 'gitignore' file (called 'exclude'), I find a command line that could help you:

```
F:\prog\git\test\.git\info>type exclude
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~
```

So....

```
git ls-files --ignored --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude

git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard
git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard
```

Should do the trick.

(Thanks to [honzajde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271996/honzajde) pointing out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore/467053?noredirect=1#comment115090587_467053) that `git ls-files -o -i --exclude-from...` does *not* include cached files: only `git ls-files -i --exclude-from...` (*without* `-o`) does.)

As mentioned in the [ls-files man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html), `--others` is the important part, to show you non-cached, non-committed, normally ignored files.

`--exclude_standard` is not just a shortcut, but a way to include *all* standard "ignored patterns" settings.

> `exclude-standard`
> Add the standard git exclusions: `.git/info/exclude`, `.gitignore` in each directory, and the `user's global exclusion file`.

---

Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [batch 13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2a540e432fe5dff3cfa9d3bf7ca56db2ad12ebb9), clarifies the documentation where the `--exclude-per-directory` option was marked as deprecated, which confused readers into thinking there may be a plan to remove it in the future, which was not our intention.

See [commit 0009542](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0009542cabb808f558605f0faa8c57d3b97ed055) (24 Jan 2024) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bbc8c05](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbc8c0567026499f235058b654863c7bda19eb9e), 02 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`ls-files`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0009542cabb808f558605f0faa8c57d3b97ed055): avoid the verb "deprecate" for individual options

> When [e750951](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e750951e74fc3fc2b40a8601b70cdf6e69ec6cf2) ("`ls-files`: guide folks to `--exclude-standard` over other --exclude* options", 2023-01-13, Git v2.40.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3eda8302e5db9116580b9589de50368694f6ceba) listed in [batch #13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a6a323b31e2bcbac2518bddec71ea7ad558870eb)) updated the documentation to give greater visibility to the `--exclude-standard` option, it marked the `--exclude-per-directory` option as "deprecated".
>
> While it is technically correct that being deprecated does not necessarily mean it is planned to be removed later, it seems to cause confusion to readers, especially when we merely mean
>
> ```
> The option Y can be used to achieve the same thing as the option
> X much simpler. To those of you who aren't familiar with either
> X or Y, we would recommend to use Y when appropriate.
> ```
>
> This is especially true for `--exclude-standard` vs the combination of more granular `--exclude-from` and `--exclude-per-directory` options.
> It is true that one common combination of the granular options can be obtained by just giving the former, but that does not necessarily mean a more granular control is not necessary.
>
> State the reason why we recommend readers `--exclude-standard` in the description of `--exclude-per-directory`, instead of saying that the option is deprecated.
> Also, spell out the recipe to emulate what `--exclude-standard` does, so that the users can give it minute tweaks (like "do the same as Git Porcelain, except I do not want to read the global exclusion file from core.excludes").

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0009542cabb808f558605f0faa8c57d3b97ed055/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L122-L125):

> directory and its subdirectories in .  If you are
> trying to emulate the way Porcelain commands work, using
> the `--exclude-standard` option instead is easier and more
> thorough.

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0009542cabb808f558605f0faa8c57d3b97ed055/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L326-L337):

> Generally, you should be able to use `--exclude-standard` when you
> want the exclude rules applied the same way as what Porcelain
> commands do.  To emulate what `--exclude-standard` specifies, you
> can give `--exclude-per-directory=.gitignore`, and then specify:
>
> 1. The file specified by the `core.excludesfile` configuration
>    variable, if exists, or the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore` file.
> 2. The `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` file.
>
> via the `--exclude-from=` option.

Comment: @VocC, from my understanding of [these tests](https://github.com/Thr4wn/myths_about_git_show_all_ignored_files), The answer you recommend at the top simply can have big flaws. That's why I would normally recommend [riyad's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1446609/10608) instead.

Comment: Since Git v2.13.2 Release: `git status --ignored` seems it also show untracked files: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.13.2.txt#L26-L27

Comment: wow, `git check-ignore -v *` works great, as it shows where the config applied. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeD To make the **/* work (or actually, you can just do **) you need globstar to be set `shopt -s globstar` after that it should work.

Comment: Without enabling (risky) globstar: `git check-ignore -v $(find . -type f -print)`

Comment: @RafiB. Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. However, wouldn't that (the find command) include files from the `.git` subfolder as well?

Comment: `git ls-files -o -i --exclude-from...` does not include cached files, only `git ls-files -i --exclude-from...` (without -o) does.

Comment: @honzajde Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly, and included your comment for more visibility.

Comment: @rafi `find . -type f -not -path './git/*' | git check-ignore --stdin`

Comment: @CervEd Thank you for this feedback, completing rafi's suggestion. I have included your command in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC the `-type f` may be superflous and perhaps undesired. I'm unsure what it does with symlinks.

Comment: @CervEd But find does not follow symlink by defauut, no? (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31121/7490) (https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Symbolic-Links.html#:~:text=find%20does%20not%20dereference%20symbolic%20links%20(except%20in%20the%20case,names%20on%20the%20command%20line.). Plus, -f is for regular file, not symlink.

Comment: @VonC what I meant was that `-type f` omits symlinks, which are still consider "files" in the git sense. Hence one might have symlinks that are ignored by .gitignore and `fint -type f` wouldn't iterate that and consequently it would not show ignored symlinks. `-type f,l` would. Or if one omits the `-type` flag altogether

Comment: @CervEd OK, got it. I have edited the answer to  remove the `-type` parameter.

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't highlight `.DS_Store` files...

Comment: @SoylentGraham By "highlight", do you mean "ignore/exclude"?

Comment: Doesn't print them out, in my case it printed out all other ignored files that were present, but not `.DS_Store`

Comment: @SoylentGraham Maybe because the folder is empty? Or it is not empty, but its content was previously added and committed?

Comment: @VonC no the folder isn't empty, it's got a `.DS_Store` file in it, which is committed, and in `.gitignore`. It should be showing up in these commands, non? (I feel it may be in my-os-git-global ignore files, but I would still expect to be able to identify it as an ignored file)

Comment: @SoylentGraham OK. It will be best to discuss this case in a new separate question.

Comment: `git check-ignore` works for me OK on Windows CMD and bash sessions, git 2.42.

Comment: @xmedeko Yes, but only in a CMD git bash session, not directly in a CMD session (because of the `*`)

Answer (score 723):

There is a much simpler way to do it (git 1.7.6+):

```
git status --ignored
```

See [Is there a way to tell git-status to ignore the effects of .gitignore files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12080857/814145)

Comment: My version is 1.7.6. Another version 1.7.5.1 is the one that requires `-s`. You may try `git status -h` to see if `--ignored` is supported

Comment: I tried every solution on this page. This is the best one. It shows both files and directories. This feature was probably not available back when this question was originally asked.  (By the way, all of the solutions won't work properly with a brand new "git init" until you've at least staged changes.)

Comment: This is certainly much better than the accepted answer. It is also much safer than the `git clean -ndX` solution, because the rare situation when one mistakenly forgets the flags will have an irrevocable effect on the repository, since untracked files are deleted. So it is dangerous. On the contrary `git status --ignored` is always safe, even when erroneously typed and it's natural to remember.

Comment: This solution worked on Windows. I recommend using `cmd` rather than PowerShell to run this. if you intend to read the output in the console as the dark red text is difficult to read on a dark blue background.

Comment: Or `git status --ignored --untracked-files=all` to display individual files in ignored directories.

Answer (score 417):

Another option that's pretty clean (No pun intended.):

```
git clean -ndX
```

Explanation:

```
$ git help clean

git-clean - Remove untracked files from the working tree
-n, --dry-run - Don't actually remove anything, just show what would be done.
-d - Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files.
-X - Remove only files ignored by Git.
```

Note: This solution will not show ignored files that have already been removed.

Comment: Nifty... however the reason I asked the original question was so that I could make sure that vendor files (*.dll) that were supposed to be there were... so deleting them would not be the desired result.

HOWEVER: this is good to know as I have changed my strategy from ignoreing *.dll to ignoring my build output folder (but not my vendor folders).  This would be a good alternative to `make clean` and very helpful on a build server.

Comment: I'm using git version 1.7.0.4, and the two commands ('git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard', 'git clean -dXn') are not equivalent. The first show me 4 files, and the second only two. (.gitignore~, index.php~, sql/create_users.sql~, www/index.php~)
(Would remove .gitignore~, Would remove index.php~). Am I missins something here?

Comment: @VonC, sweet! Thanks! @Cesar, I'm not sure. I'm not so familiar with `git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard`. `git clean -dXn` has always been what I wanted but doesn't show ignored files that have already been removed. `git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard` might do that. So, that might be what's causing the difference.

Comment: One tiny thing - it might be a good idea to type the `n` first, less chance of accidentally deleting that way; `git clean -ndX`

Comment: @TobiasCohen nice! I updated the answer with your suggestion. It's safer. Although, if you leave out the `n`, Git defaults to `fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -n nor -f given; refusing to clean`. Still pretty safe, but typing the `n` first is even safer! :)

Comment: great tip, `git clean -nxdf` works best for me, I dont know the difference.

Comment: @José the f has no effect if the n is specified. git clean -nxd, if you're happy with what it will remove then git clean -fxd to actually remove the files

Answer (score 44):

While generally correct your solution does not work in all circumstances.
Assume a repo dir like this:

```
# ls **/*                                                                                                       
doc/index.html  README.txt  tmp/dir0/file0  tmp/file1  tmp/file2

doc:
index.html

tmp:
dir0  file1  file2

tmp/dir0:
file0
```

and a .gitignore like this:

```
# cat .gitignore
doc
tmp/*
```

This ignores the `doc` directory and all files below `tmp`.
Git works as expected, but the given command for listing the ignored files does not.
Lets have a look at what git has to say:

```
# git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard                                                            
tmp/file1
tmp/file2
```

Notice that `doc` is missing from the listing.
You can get it with:

```
# git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard --directory                                                
doc/
```

Notice the additional `--directory` option.

From my knowledge there is no *one* command to list all ignored files at once.
But I don't know why `tmp/dir0` does not show up at all.

Comment: This got me what I wanted, whereas the others did not (for my particular case)... thanks!  It's frustrating to have to run two commands, but with an ignored directory, the --directory option at least finds me that, and I can pipe that into a find command to find the files.  Thanks!

Comment: This does it all at once, and expands the directories: `(git ls-files -oi --exclude-standard; git ls-files -oi --exclude-standard --directory) | perl -nle '$seen{$_}++||next;if(-d){system"find",$_,"-type","f"}else{print}'`

Answer (score 23):

Git now has this functionality built in

```
git check-ignore *
```

Of course you can change the glob to something like `**/*.dll` in your case

[Git Reference](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)

Comment: `git check-ignore **/*` to include files in subdirectories

Comment: this only lists the top level dicrectories.

Comment: Too bad that the built-in is not human-readable, for example, it list everything in `vendor` and `node_modules` directories, see my answer for a human-readable version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66922010/8740349

Answer (score 17):

Here's how to print the complete list of files in the working tree which match patterns located anywhere in Git's multiple gitignore sources (if you're using GNU `find`):

```sh
$ cd {your project directory}
$ find . -path ./.git -prune -o -print \
| git check-ignore --no-index --stdin --verbose
```

It will check all the files in the current branch of the repository (unless you've deleted them locally).

And it identifies the particular gitignore source lines, as well.

Git continues to track changes in some files which match gitignore patterns, simply because those files were added already. Usefully, the above command displays those files, too.

Negative gitignore patterns are also matched. However, these are easily distinguishable in the listing, because they begin with `!`.

If you're using Windows, [Git Bash](http://git-for-windows.github.io/) includes GNU `find` (as revealed by `find --version`).

If the list is long (and you have `rev`), you can display them by extension (somewhat), too:

```sh
$ cd {your project directory}
$ find . -path ./.git -prune -o -print \
| git check-ignore --no-index --stdin --verbose \
| rev | sort | rev
```

For more details, see `man find`, `man git-check-ignore`, `man rev`, and `man sort`.

The point of this whole approach is that Git (the software) is changing rapidly and is highly complex. By contrast, GNU's `find` is *extremely* stable (at least, in its features used here). So, anyone who desires to be competitive by displaying their in-depth knowledge of Git will answer the question in a different way.

What's the best answer? *This* answer deliberately minimizes its reliance on Git knowledge, toward achieving the goal of stability and simplicity through modularity (information isolation), and is designed to last a *long* time.

Comment: Much thanks! I had been struggling to figure out why some of my new source files occasionally have been missing from my commits. Turns out that I had a pattern: bin*, that I thought would match only names of files/directories starting with bin but instead it matches anything that includes bin in the full path of a file/directory! I guess, my problem comes from a misunderstanding of the precise semantics of pattern matching in .gitignore. Your 2-line script helped me find this mistake!

Answer (score 15):

It should be sufficient to use

```
git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard
```

as that covers everything covered by

```
git ls-files --others -i --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
```

therefore the latter is redundant.

---

You can make this easier by adding an alias to your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
git config --global alias.ignored "ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard"
```

Now you can just type `git ignored` to see the list.  Much easier to remember, and faster to type.

If you prefer the more succinct display of Jason Geng's solution, you can add an alias for that like this:

```
git config --global alias.ignored "status --ignored -s"
```

However the more verbose output is more useful for troubleshooting problems with your .gitignore files, as it lists every single cotton-pickin' file that is ignored.  You would normally pipe the results through `grep` to see if a file you expect to be ignored is in there, or if a file you don't want to be ignore is in there.

```
git ignored | grep some-file-that-isnt-being-ignored-properly
```

Then, when you just want to see a short display, it's easy enough to remember and type

```
git status --ignored
```

(The `-s` can normally be left off.)

Comment: This never worked for me, because you have to manually list those files. `git status --ignored` works on Debian sid but may be very new… but apparently it got added due to popular demand ;-)

Comment: By "works on Debian sid" I assume you mean "works with the version of Git installed by default on Debian sid"?  You should really avoid letting yourself be held hostage by the versions of utilities included in your distro.  You can upgrade them independently of the distro itself.

Answer (score 6):

If you just need a **valid list of files** ignored (no matter how they got ignored), and **without any extra notice and logs.**

Once created, anywhere (in Git-bash) run:

```
git ignore-list
```

#### Create it by executing:

```
git config --global alias.ignore-list "! cd -- \"\${GIT_PREFIX:-.}\" && git ls-files -v \${1:-.} | sed -n -e \"s,^[a-z] \(.*\)$,\${GIT_PREFIX:-./}\1,p\" && git status --ignored --porcelain \${1:-.} 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e \"s/^\(\\!\\! \)\(.*\)$/\2/p\" #"
```

> **Example usage,**
> Assuming it's the initial commit and you want to push everything, try:
>
> ```
> git ignore-list | xargs git add -f
> ```

#### Notes:

1. It's tested and works on both `macOS` and `Windows` platforms!
2. Once you `cd` into a directory, lists only files ignored from that dir (or its sub-dirs).
3. And lastly, always logs paths relative to root-dir (which contains `.git` dir, no matter what dir you `cd` into).

Another useful thing is Human-readability, like if an entire directory is ignored, something like `build` or `node_modules`, this will log dir-name only.
While `git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard` command logs each and every file (good for `xargs`).

Answer (score 1):

I would just do

```
git status --porcelain --ignored
```

and to only list the ignored files

```
git status --porcelain --ignored | grep '^[!][!] '
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd).

The command to run is:

```
comm -23 <(fd -HI | sort) <(fd -H | sort)
```

Please note that in case there is no `.git` directory and only a `.gitignore` file (ex. bare repo), you have to specifically tell where the .gitignore file is.

```
comm -23 <(fd -HI | sort) <(fd -H --ignore-file .gitignore | sort)
```

To be more specific, use `--no-ignore-vcs` instead of `-I`

For more details please check [here](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd/issues/1032#issuecomment-1148439224).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming there are a few ignore directories, why not use "git status node/logs/" which will tell you what files are to be added? In the directory I have a text file that is not part of status output, e.g.:

On branch master
  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
  Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
    node/logs/.gitignore
```

.gitignore is:

*
!.gitignore

Answer (score -1):

<sub>(extending the other answers)</sub>

Note, `git check-ignore` uses the committed `.gitignore` and not the one in your working tree! To play with it without polluting your git history, you might freely try to edit it, and then commit with a `git commit --amend`.

This problem happens mainly if you need a workaround of the problem, that git doesn't follow directories. Enter in the `.gitignore`:

```
dirtokeep/**
!dirtokeep/.keep
```

`.keep` should be a zero-length file in `dirtokeep`.

The result will be that *everything* in `dirtokeep` will be ignored, *except* `dirtokeep/.keep`, which will result that also the `dirtokeep` directory will be constructed on clone/checkout.