# Match all files under all nested directories with shell globbing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shopt

Is there a way to use shell globbing to identify nested directories?

so if I have dir/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/.. and I have files under all of them, what is the equivalent globbing pattern to match all files under all directories, similar to - for example - `ls -R`

Comment: Voted to move to SuperUser.com. Also why is this tagged 'git'?

Comment: gitignore doesn't use shell globbing; that's a separate question.

Comment: Similar: [What expands to all files in current directory recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1690809/55075) at SO

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Bash 4, with `shopt -s globstar`, and zsh you can use `**/*` which will include everything except hidden files. You can do `shopt -s dotglob` in Bash 4 or `setopt dotglob` in zsh to cause hidden files to be included.

In ksh, `set -o globstar` enables it. I don't think there's a way to include dot files implicitly, but I think `**/{.[^.],}*` works.

Comment: That's cool! will files parsed for shell globbing (like for example .gitignore) use those settings?

Comment: @Samer Abukhait: If the shell is doing the globbing then it should.

Comment: @Samer: But gitignore isn't using shell globbing, it's using fnmatch.

Answer (score 6):

Specifically about git (gitignore, gitattributes, and commands that take filenames): if the pattern contains no slash, `*` wildcards will match deep. If it does contain a slash, [git will call fnmatch](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) with the [`FNM_PATHNAME`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Matching.html) flag, and simple wildcards won't match slashes. `**` to match deep isn't supported. Maybe this kind of deep matching could be more widely supported with a new `FNM_STARSTAR` flag, and an implementation in glibc, gnulib and other places.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to act on all the files returned by find, rather than just list them, you can pipe them to xargs:

```
find <directory> -type f | xargs ls
```

But this is only for commands that don't have a recursive flag.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
**/*.*
```

However it'll ignore hidden files (such as `.git` files). Sometimes it's a life-saver.

<sup>Read more at: [What expands to all files in current directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29731174/55075) at SO</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with vanilla Bash, however most commands accept a `-R` or `--recursive` option to tell them to descend into directories.

If you simply want to list all files located anywhere within a directory or its sub-directories, you can use [find](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm).

To recursively find files (`-type f`) with a given directory:

```
find <directory> -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tree, it will show all folders recursively.

```
tree <path>
```