# Is there a globbing pattern to match by file extension, both PWD and recursively?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, glob

**I need to match files *only with one specific extension* under all nested directories, including the PWD, with BASH using "[globbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229465/what-is-file-globbing)".**

- I do not need to [Match ***all files*** under all nested directories with shell globbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349082/match-all-files-under-all-nested-directories-with-shell-globbing), but not in the PWD.
- I need to match files using commands *other than* [***grep*** search all directories with filename extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72245606/grep-search-all-directories-with-filename-extension)
- I do not need to only [***grep*** recursively, but only in files with certain extension***s** (plural)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516937/how-can-i-grep-recursively-but-only-in-files-with-certain-extensions)
- `set -o globstar; ls **/*.*` is great for *all* files (not my question).

  - `ls **/*.php` does not match in the PWD.
  - `set -o globstar; **/*.php` returns duplicate files.
- `grep -r --include=\*.php "find me" ./` is specifically for `grep`, not globbing (consider [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349082/match-all-files-under-all-nested-directories-with-shell-globbing)). It seems `grep` has `--include=GLOB` because this is not possible using globbing.

From [this Answer (here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72246808/10343144), I believe there may not be a way to do this using globbing.

## tl;dr

I need:

- A glob expression
- To match *any* command where simple globs can be used (`ls`, `sed`, `cp`, `cat`, `chown`, `rm`, et cetera)
- Mainly in BASH, but other shells would be interesting
- Both in the PWD and all subdirectories recursively
- For files with a specific extension

I'm using `grep` & `ls` only as examples, but I need a glob expression that applies to other commands also.

- `grep -r --include=GLOB` is not a glob expression for, say, `cp`; it is a workaround specific to `grep` and is not a solution.
- `find` is not a glob, but it may be a workaround for non-`grep` commands if there is no such glob expression. It would need `|` or `while do;`, et cetera.

### Examples

Suppose I have these files, all containing "find me":

```sh
./file1.js
./file2.php
./inc/file3.js
./inc/file4.php
./inc.php/file5.js
./inc.php/file6.php
```

I need to match only/all **.php** one time:

```sh
./file2.php
./inc/file4.php
./inc.php/file6.php
```

### Duplicates returned: `shopt -s globstar; ... **/*.php`

This changes the problem; it does not solve it.

#### Dup: `ls`

**Before** entering `shopt -s globstar` as a single command...

`ls **/*.php` returns:

```sh
inc/file4.php
inc.php/file5.js
inc.php/file6.php
```

- file2.php does not return.

**After** entering `shopt -s globstar` as a single command...

`ls **/*.php` returns:

```sh
file2.php
inc/file4.php
inc.php/file6.php

inc.php:
file5.js
file6.php
```

- inc.php/file6.php returns twice.

#### Dup: `grep`

**Before** entering `shopt -s globstar` as a single command...

`grep -R "find me" **/*.php` returns:

```sh
inc/file4.php: find me
inc.php/file6.php: find me
```

- file2.php does not return.

**After** entering `shopt -s globstar` as a single command...

`grep -R "find me" **/*.php` returns:

```sh
file2.php: find me
inc/file4.php: find me
inc.php/file5.js: find me
inc.php/file6.php: find me
inc.php/file6.php: find me
```

- inc.php/file6.php returns twice.

  - After seeing the duplicate seen from the `ls` output, we know why.

### Current solution: faulty misuse of `&&` logic

```sh
grep -r "find me" *.php && grep -r "find me" */*.php
ls -l *.php && ls -l */*.php
```

- Please no! `I fail here && so I never happen`

### Desired solution: single command via globbing

```sh
grep -r "find me" [GLOB]
ls -l [GLOB]
```

---

### Insight from `grep`

`grep` does have the `--include` flag, which achieves the same result but using a flag specific to `grep`. `ls` does not have an `--include` option. This leads me to believe that there is no such glob expression, which is why `grep` has this flag.

Comment: `-r` of grep will by default include the PWD. It looks like adding `--include` makes it somehow not match files in the current dir. I wouldn't expect that and it could be a bug …

Comment: @knittl `-r` includes *.php files in the PWD, but only subdirs that also match *.php, I want *.php files in both the PWD and all subdirs regardless of containing .php in the name. I still can't find a way.

Comment: This is about specific file extensions, not *all files* as in the proposed [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349082/match-all-files-under-all-nested-directories-with-shell-globbing). That solution applied here only changes the problem; it does not solve it. It could work for `... **/*`, such as addressed by "all files" in the proposed dup Question, but not with a specified file extension like *.php in my Question.

Comment: I don't understand why the solution with `find -exec` doesn't help you

Comment: I don't understand why people think this is a programming problem, and it keeps getting closed as a duplicate.  That said: on my installation (Ubuntu 20.04, grep (GNU grep) 3.4) `grep -R --include="*.php"  "Starting" .` does exactly what you're asking, I can't imagine why it doesn't for you.

Comment: [Please don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/248627) repeat [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72245606/354577). You have edited your original question. Great! That puts it in a queue to be considered for reopening. It has already earned two votes to reopen. A third will do it. Posting the same question again is counterproductive.

Comment: Reopen, pls. How can I explain that globs, useful for multiple commands, with file extension, both PWD and recursive... are all criteria that haven't turned up in any of the proposed dups?

Comment: @Chris, from the "close" instructions on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72245606): *Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.*

Comment: @sideshowbarker That is MY own Question about using `grep`. This is a Question about **globs**, which clearly says that **globs** don't seem able, so `grep` uses a **flag** instead of a **glob**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With shell globing it is possible to only get directories by adding a `/` at the end of the glob, but there's no way to exclusively get files (`zsh` being an exception)

###### Illustration:

With the given tree:

```
file.php
inc.php/include.php
lib/lib.php
```

Supposing that the shell supports the non-standard `**` glob:

- `**/*.php/` expands to `inc.php/`
- `**/*.php` expands to `file.php inc.php inc.php/include.php lib/lib.php`
- For getting `file.php inc.php/include.php lib/lib.php`, you **cannot** use a glob.
  <sub>=> with `zsh` it would be `**/*.php(.)`</sub>

###### Standard work-around (any shell, any OS)

The POSIX way to recursively get the files that match a given *standard* glob and then apply a command to them is to use `find -type f -name ... -exec ...`:

- `ls -l <all .php files>` would be:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec ls -l {} +
```

- `grep "finde me" <all .php files>` would be:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep "finde me" {} +
```

- `cp <all .php files> ~/destination/` would be:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.php' -type f -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" ~/destination/' _ {} +
```

<sup>**remark:** This one is a little more tricky because you need `~/destination/` to be **after** the file arguments, and `find`'s syntax doesn't allow `find -exec ... {} ~/destination/ +`</sup>

Comment: This helps with globbing knowledge in general, which I make room for, so I'm upvoting. But my Question wants globs that can go into any command directly. This is essentially a workaround that would need a `|`. It is useful within scope, but it's doesn't address the full Question, so I won't mark it "correct'. Just explaining. But, thanks for this, really.

Comment: See my update for a direct answer to your question. btw, why would you need a `|` in the examples with `find`?

Comment: ...a `|` or `--exec` or `while do;`.... workaround is workaround. If it's not possible and this is the way, then that's right.

Comment: You can remove your "Update" line ;-)

Comment: The last example could be simplified to `-exec cp -t ~/destination/ {} +` for efficiency if you have GNU `cp`, but it is useful as a template for how to solve the broader problem of processing one file at a time with `-exec ... +`

Comment: @tripleee Nice, I didn't know about `cp -t`, but do you say _"one file at a time"_? `-exec 'cp "$@" dir/' {} +` will dopy a bunch of them at a time

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that the `sh -c 'for ... done' _ {} ` loop demonstrates how to process one file at a time with a single subprocess.

Answer (score 3):

With bash, you can first do a `shopt -s globstar` to enable recursive matching, and then the pattern `**/*.php` will expand to all the files in the current directory tree that have a .php extension.

zsh and ksh93 also support this syntax. Other commands that take a glob pattern as an argument and do their own expansion of it (like your `grep --include`) likely won't.

Comment: For bash, `globstar` was introduced in bash 4.0

Comment: @Fravadona `**/*.php` works with `ls **/*.php` without `shopt -s globstar` first, but with `shopt -s globstar`, a .php file in a .php directory gets listed twice. This is helpful, and may be the best answer, but it doesn't solve my problem because 1. it's not a single command, it's a setting, then 2. it returns duplicate items. But, thanks, upvoting.

Comment: @JesseSteele if you have a directory ending in .php the glob will expand it and if it's an argument to ls, ls will list the contents of the directory...

Comment: If you just want to display names, use `printf "%s\n" **/*.php` instead of `ls **/*.php` (or find. ls is so often misused... See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs )

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting different strategy:

Use explicit `find` command to build `bash` command(s) on the selected files using `-printf` option.

Inspect the command for correctness and run.

##### 1. preparing `bash` commands on selected files

```
 find . -type f -name "*.php" -printf "cp %p ~/destination/ \n"
```

##### 2. inspect the output, correct command, correct filter, test

```
cp ./file2.php ~/destination/
cp ./inc/file4.php ~/destination/
cp ./inc.php/file5.php ~/destination/
```

##### 3. execute prepared `find` output

```
 bash <<< $(find . -type f -name "*.php" -printf "cp %f ~/destination/ \n")
```

Comment: So, in other words, you're recommending `find` as a way to work around this problem because it's possible that glob expressions can't do this. It doesn't solve my problem, but I'm upvoting because it does help explain what is going on and how files work.