# what does **/*.java mean in java classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

So I saw this line in the .classpath file(eclipse file) today

`<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>`

I know `*.java` means any java file, but what does that `**/` before it do? Does it mean to include every subfolder under `src/main/java`?

Comment: Is a .classpath file an eclipse file?  You should probably tag/mention that appropriately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> a single star (*) matches zero or more characters within a path name.
>   a double star `(**)` matches zero or more characters across directory
>   levels. Another way to think about it is double star `(**)` matches
>   slash (/) but single star (*) does not.

So let's say I have these classes:

```
1. src/test.java
2. test/src/test.java
```

Well `*/*.java` matches 1 only where as `**/*.java` matches both because ** matches any number of levels

Answer (score 7):

> Does it mean to include every subfolder under src/main/java?

Yes. I think it is a relatively common pattern in glob-style expressions. See for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690809/what-expands-to-all-files-in-current-directory-recursively) about its use in the bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

It means every sub folder under `src/main/java` and ending with `.java`