# How to recursively get all files filtered by multiple extensions within a folder including working folder without using find in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this question after quite a day of searching the net, perhaps I'm doing something wrong , here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

FILE_EXTENSIONS=properties\|xml\|sh\|sql\|ksh
SOURCE_FOLDER=$1

if [ -z "$SOURCE_FOLDER" ]; then
   SOURCE_FOLDER=$(pwd)
fi # Set directory to current working folder if no input parameter.

for file in $SOURCE_FOLDER/**/*.*($FILE_EXTENSIONS)
do
    echo Working with file: $file
done
```

Basically, I want to recursively get all the files filtered by a list of extensions within folders from a directory that is passed as an argument including the directory itself.

I would like to know if there is a way of doing this and how without the use of the **find** command.

Imagine I have this file tree:

- bin/props.properties
- bin/xmls.xml
- bin/source/sources.sh
- bin/config/props.properties
- bin/config/folders/moreProps.xml

My script, as it is right now and running from */bin*, would echo:

> - bin/source/sources.sh
> - bin/config/props.properties
> - bin/config/folders/moreProps.xml

Leaving the ones in the working path aside.

P.S. I know this can be done with **find** but I really want to know if there's another way for the sake of learning.

Thanks!

Comment: Good first question, but [it has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690809/what-expands-to-all-files-in-current-directory-recursively). So in your case, `$SOURCE_FOLDER/{,**/}*.*($FILE_EXTENSIONS)` should work

Comment: Or just split it up into two globs `$SOURCE_FOLDER/**/*.*($FILE_EXTENSIONS) $SOURCE_FOLDER/*.*($FILE_EXTENSIONS)`. Though I think the first brace expansion syntax is cleaner

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! This was confusing to me, you can tell by the way my question and the duplicate are made jeje. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **find** with **grep**, just like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE_FOLDER=$1
EXTENSIONS="properties|xml|sh|sql|ksh"

find $SOURCE_FOLDER | grep -E ".(${EXTENSIONS})"

#or even better
find $SOURCE_FOLDER -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*(${EXTENSIONS})"
```