# bash globbing (globstar) pattern errors if top level directory empty with "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, glob, ls

I have a folder structure as such:

```
a/
  b/
    test.js
  c/
    another_test.js
```

When I want to find all these files, I tried the globstar approach:

```
ls a/{,**/}*.js
```

However, this command errors (but still outputs files) because there is no `a/*.jsx` file:

```
$ ls a/{,**/}*.jsx
    ls: a/*.jsx: No such file or directory
    a/b/test.js
```

I **want to use this specific glob** because in the future, at some point, `a/test.js` could exist.

**Is there a glob pattern** that will find all `.js` files in `a/` recursively and not error?

I looked at some of the options in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690809/what-expands-to-all-files-in-current-directory-recursively) but couldn't find anything that doesn't error and lists all files.

Comment: just use `ls a/**/*.js`

Comment: That does not find `a/test.js`

Comment: it does if you have globstar enabled, otherwise `**` is only `*`

Comment: Hmm, osx doesn't have a `globstar` option, at least not with the bash it ships with.

Comment: then why did you put globstar in your question?

Comment: I still think that's the proper term, and it's inherently on in osx bash?

Comment: it's *not* on because it's an option that was introduced in a later version

Answer (score 2):

With bash4 and above, just use:
`ls dir/**/*.js`

With previous bash versions, such as 3.2 shipped with osx, you can use find:
`find dir -name '*.js'`

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
% tree .
.
└── a
    ├── b
    │   └── test.js
    └── c
        └── another_test.js
```

You can use the pattern `a/**/*.js` on either zsh or Bash4+ with `shopt -s globstar` set:

zsh:

```
% ls -1 a/**/*.js
a/b/test.js
a/c/another_test.js
```

Bash 5.1:

```
$ ls -1 a/**/*.js
a/b/test.js
a/c/another_test.js
```