# Bash glob pattern behaviour different between terminal and shell script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, glob

I have a glob pattern `{,**/}*.*` for recursing through all files in current directory plus children. In the terminal if I run `echo {,**/}*.*` it outputs all of the files in the current directory plus the nested directories. When I run a shell script which contains this line it only does one directory deep.

I understand that [terminal has different behaviour than the shell](https://superuser.com/a/715018/665794): adding `shopt -s extglob` made no difference.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
echo {,**/}*.*
```

I am on MacOSX with [Bash 4 terminal](https://gist.github.com/reggi/475793ea1846affbcfe8) and `shopt -s globstar` enabled.

Comment: But did you enable `globstar` in the script?

Comment: If I add `shopt -s globstar` it errors saying: "./show-glob.sh: line 3: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name"

Comment: Running `shopt globstar` in terminal outputs `globstar        on`

Comment: Are you sure you're running it with bash 4?

Comment: `$bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.5(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.`

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` on OSX points to BASH 3.2 not BASH 4

Comment: You probably want `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` at the start of your script

Comment: There is no inherent difference between the terminal and a script; it depends on which shell each is running.

Comment: I changed start of script to `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` t, and added `bash --version`. Shows that Bash 4 is running, still doesn't work as expected: `$./show-glob.sh 
GNU bash, version 4.4.5(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)`

Comment: Do you still get the `"./show-glob.sh: line 3: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name" ` or another error ?

Comment: Boom, you are right. The following works: `#!/usr/local/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

echo {,**/}*.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Aserre and @anubhava, it was indeed the combination of bash path and making sure globstar was enabled (for MacOSX). Full script is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

echo {,**/}*.*
```

And yes `./**` would suffice but that wasn't my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`{,**/}*.*` will not give you  *all files in current directory plus children.* Instead it would give you results of the format

```
directory/file.ext
```

You might have used `./**` instead

If you globstar, `**` will expand to everything in the folder. ie do

```
shopt -s globstar
echo ./** # this would suffice
```

Apart from that, borrowing [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285593/bash-glob-pattern-behaviour-different-between-terminal-and-shell-script#comment69773200_41285593) comment, you need to use a shell version that supports globstar. This is evident from you [getting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285593/bash-glob-pattern-behaviour-different-between-terminal-and-shell-script#comment69773716_41285593)

```
shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name
```

Then,

```
#!/bin/bash -> #!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

should do the job

Comment: According to the comments in the Question, OP has enabled globstar in his interactive shell and receives an error when enabling it in his script. His issue is related to his shebang.

Comment: @Aserre : My emphasis was on the glob pattern. `for recursing through all files in current directory plus children`, `{,**/}*.*`seems overly  complicated.

Comment: Actually, I want to include the current directory, and I don't want folders, so my glob is based on the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1691202/158815

Comment: @mummybot : I see, then what you did is the perfect way to do it.