# Enable wildcards behave recursively

Tags: bash

I'd like to make a statistics of the words from all the `txt` file from the current directory and its subdiretories.

```
In [39]: ls
about.txt            distutils/           installing/          whatsnew/
bugs.txt             extending/           library/             word.txt
c-api/               faq/                 license.txt          words_frequency.txt
contents.txt         glossary.txt         reference/
copyright.txt        howto/               tutorial/
distributing/        install/             using
```

I firstly tried command:

```
 In [46]: !grep -Eoh '[a-zA-Z]+' *.txt | nl
```

There's a problem that files in the subdiretories were not found:

```
 In [45]: !echo *.txt
 about.txt bugs.txt contents.txt copyright.txt glossary.txt license.txt word.txt words_frequency.txt
```

I improved it as:

```
In [48]: ! echo */*.txt | grep "about.txt"
In [49]:
```

Problem again, It failed to find the files of Level one directory and cannot traverse the files of random length.

It's interesting that python has a soluton to this problem:

```
In [50]: files = glob.glob("**/*.txt", recursive=True)
In [54]: files.index('about.txt')
Out[54]: 4
```

It could traverse dirs recursively to find all `txt` files.

However, python is cumbersome to move around files and change text data as `grep "pattern" *.txt`

How to enable the wildcards as greedy as a recursive behavior.

As an alternative, `find` command helps

```
find . -regex -E ".*\.txt" -print0 -exec grep -Eoh "{}" "[a-zA-Z]+" | nl \;
```

Which not handy as a greedy wildcards if possible.

The `globstar` could not be activated on Macos.

```
$ shopt -s globstar
-bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0)
```

Comment: Are you looking for - [What expands to all files in current directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1690809/5291015)

Comment: I appreciate it very much if you leave an answer. @Inian

Comment: If you find that useful, then it is a duplicate of that question. I've to mark it such. The site guidelines rules out answering a known duplicate

Comment: ty, globstar could not be activate on Macos. @Inian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly you may use something like this:

```
find -type f -name '*.txt' -exec /bin/grep -hEo '\w+' {} \; \
  | sort \
  | uniq -c \
  | sort -k1,1n
```