# Replace string in multiple files recursively

Tags: bash, sed, find

I have multiple files named `dev.rc` in a very huge folder structure. These files are containing environment variables, like:

```
...
FOO=bar
...
```

I want to replace bar string along all the project with the string `baz`

I tried to pipe some bash commands like: `find` and `sed` but I cannot save the content of the replaced string in the original file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to look for all the files that match the filename and then execute a simple `sed` command and save the content, having an automatic string replacement, as follows:

```
for f in `find . -name dev.rc`; do      
  sed -i '' 's/bar/baz/g' $f
done
```

Or you can also use `exec`:

```
find . -name 'dev.rc' -type f -exec sed -i '' 's/bar/baz/g' {} +
```

Comment: You should quote `'{}'` in your `find` example (and indent it another space so it formats correctly)

Comment: Looping through `find` output this way is not robust - it will break if the file path contains whitespaces.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've found that you don't have to quote `{}` in a `find -exec`, have you ever run into problems with it?

Comment: Well, no, not in bash, but I'm not sure that holds for all shells. By quoting, you insure no word-splitting on the filename even if it includes spaces.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Apparently non-POSIX shells such as fish can run into trouble with unquoted `{}`: https://superuser.com/questions/995617/difference-between-and-in-find-command

Answer (score 0):

Use [globstar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1690809/6862601) to traverse through the files:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for file in **/dev.rc; do
  sed -i "s/=bar/=baz/" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive written a simple PHP script to do it for you.
Save it as a .php file and use it in apache localhost or run as php
Remember to edit the last line of the code with your info

```
<?php
/*
THIS IS COMMENT SECTION TO HELP YOU
$filecount = How much files you have to replace
$location = Location of your file ; Example "usr/bk/file.txt"
$string = The string you want to replace
$newstring = The new string you want to put
*/


function replace($filecount,$location,$string,$newstring){
     for($i = 0; $i>= $filecount; $i++)
     $file = file_get_contents($location);
     file_put_contents($file,str_replace($string,$newstring,$file));
     }
}

/*
Remember to replace the variables of the function using "","",""
Below is an example calling the function, replace with your own:
*/

replace(10,"/usr/locationhere.zip","foo","bar","baz");
```