# How to list files ignored by git that are currently staged or committed?

Tags: git

How does one get a list of those files that match a rule in .gitignore file, but that have been staged or committed in the past?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show ignored files in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git)

Comment: Of the answers on the other question, the one you're looking for is `git ls-files -i --exclude-standard` or possibly a variation on it.

Comment: From what I understand, this is NOT a duplicate of [show ignored files in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git).  That question is asking how to list untracked files that are ignored.  This question is asking how to list files that are tracked (and thus exempt from the ignore rules) but would be ignored if they weren't tracked.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The documentation to `ls-files` is not exactly clearly written, but it appears that the following simple alias does the job:

```
git config --global alias.showtrackedignored "ls-files -i --exclude-standard"
```

The above command creates an alias called `showtrackedignored`.  To use, run:

```
git showtrackedignored
```

and it will list all of the files in the current directory and subdirectories that are tracked but would be ignored if they weren't tracked.

### Bug in `git ls-files`

Unfortunately, this doesn't work 100% reliably.  Apparently Git does a good job of finding files that should **not** be ignored, but when searching for files that **are** ignored (the `-i` option to `git ls-files`), it doesn't list ignored files inside a directory if it's the directory that matches the ignore rules.

To work around this bug, try converting your ignore rules so that only files are matched, not directories (this isn't always possible).

(Thank you [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599884/christoph) for discovering this bug and [reporting it to the Git mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/198795)! Edit: A patch is in the works now and will make it into git 1.7.11.2 or later)

### Alternative approach

Here's a different approach.  It's far more complicated and might have broken corner cases.

```
git config --global alias.showtrackedignored '!
cd "${GIT_PREFIX}" &&
untracked_list=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/ignored-untracked.txt &&
git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard >"${untracked_list}" &&
GIT_INDEX_FILE="" git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard | grep -Fvxf "${untracked_list}" &&
rm -rf "${untracked_list}"'
```

The alias does the following:

- `cd` back to the directory where `git showtrackedignored` was run from (Git runs shell-based aliases from the toplevel directory, not the current directory; see the section on `alias.*` in `git help config`)
- Define a variable called `untracked_list`.  This variable holds the path to a temporary file that will contain the list of currently ignored files.  This temporary file is in the `.git` directory.
- Write the list of ignored files to `${untracked_list}`.
- Tell Git to act as if the index is empty and list all the ignored files.
- Pipe that output to `grep`, which filters out the files that were written to `${untracked_list}`.
- Delete the temporary file `${untracked_list}`.

Drawbacks to this approach:

- It creates a temporary file in your `.git` directory.
- It assumes you have a POSIX-compatible shell.
- It assumes you have a POSIX-compatible implementation of `grep`.

It also suffers from the same bug as the former alias.

Comment: Have there been changes to git recently which break this script? It worked pretty great since I found it, but I recently discovered that it does not discover all files/folder (or maybe just folders) which have been committed but match an ignore pattern. I'm on git 1.7.9.5. Any ideas?

Comment: @Christoph: Works for me with 1.7.10 on Linux (Ubuntu).  Try manually running each command separately to see which part of the script is misbehaving.  If you find the problem, let me know and I'll update my answer.  Also, let me know if you can create an example repository that exhibits the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I created a repo which exhibits the problem for me. Read the full commit messages where I have detailed the procedure. https://github.com/bilderbuchi/test-git-showtrackedignored

Comment: @Christoph:  I can reproduce the problem.  It looks like a Git bug to me.  Which version of Git were you using when it worked?

Comment: @Christoph: `git help ignore` says "`foo/` will match a directory `foo` and paths underneath it".  Apparently the "paths underneath it" part works when Git is trying to identify the files that are **not** ignored, but is broken when Git is trying to identify the files that **are** ignored.

Comment: I was using the previous Ubuntu release, 11.10, so it most probably was git 1.7.5.4-1

Comment: Now that I think of it harder, I guess it's possible that this didn't work correctly before (i just assumed it did), either, and it was just exposed now. Are you aware of any bug reports regarding the git bug?

Comment: I've fired off a mail to the git mailing list about this.

Comment: thank you for updating this. I would upvote again if I could. Unfortunately, converting directory ignores is not feasibly in my case. I hope I will hear back from the git mailing list.

Comment: Nowadays, `git ls-files -i --exclude-standard` is really the cleaner and correctly working approach. I have a repo here where the conventional alias gives wrong results.

Comment: @Christoph:  Thanks, I edited the answer to put the simpler approach at the top and to add a warning to the complex approach.

Comment: If you want to see *why* they're ignored, try this `git ls-files -i --exclude-standard | xargs git check-ignore -v  --no-index`

Answer (score 28):

Just going to leave this one here, based on Richard's answer:

`git ls-files --cached -i --exclude-standard`

To **delete** every tracked file that is ignored by `.gitignore`:

`git ls-files --cached -i --exclude-standard | xargs git rm --cached`

Comment: This code is dangerous if someone just wants to list files (as per OP question) and not necessarily delete, yet quickly copy paste! Might be worth writing it in two distinct lines?

Comment: To run this on repositories with spaces in the paths, use null-delimited input/output as follows:
`git ls-files -z --cached -i --exclude-standard | xargs -0 git rm --cached`.  

`-z` tells git-ls-files to output each path with null-terminator, mirrored by `-0` on the xargs-side of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers only show files that are currently ignored but exist in the working-tree/index.

To see files that are currently ignored but checked in in the past (and possibly now deleted)

```sh
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A `# all files ever` \
| sed '/^$/d' `# skip git-logs empty lines` \
| sort -u `# sort + unique` \
| tr '\n' '\0' `# null separate for xargs` \
| xargs -0 git check-ignore # check if they are ignored
```

Not sure if renamed files are displayed multiple times or not.

#### edit:

Fix formatting and skip `git-log` empty lines

Answer (score -3):

This question was answered well by https://stackoverflow.com/a/467053.  Basically, git clean -ndX will tell you what can be safely ignored.

Comment: That lists un-tracked files and directories, and if you drop the `d`, then it lists un-tracked files along with staged and committed.  To my mind it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Hedgehog: It is a duplicate, but seth has picked the wrong answer from it.

Comment: I don't dispute they are in the same neighbourhood, but that they are not duplicate questions seems to be clear from the observation that it is not clear which, if any, of those answers does precisely this.  The  question in [Show ignored files in git](http://stackoverflow.com/a/467053) is "list what files exist that are ignored"