# I'd need clarification as to how files are ignored, with the .gitignore file

Tags: git

I've been using Git for 5 years. And I know about the .gitignore file. I used it all of the time, whenever I create a new Git repo, either on GitHub or Azure DevOps.

But I've got a new situation, in which I'm trying to migrate several TFVC repos out of our old TFS server to GitHub. I have been following blog post [Migrate From TFVC To Git – 5 Simple Steps](https://www.scrum-tips.com/agile/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/). I added the .gitignore file in step #3 as that blog post said to do. However, the TFVC repo had several DLLs, PDBs, OBJs, etc. files in it, which are now in the new Git repo. I know that the .gitignore file I used for Visual Studio, will prevent adding new DLLs being added, but I don't know what happens when a developer builds the app. For example, suppose there's a DLL named File1.dll, in the build folder which is now in the new Git repo. Will rebuilding the app, generating a new File1.dll, mean that new instance of the File1.dll will be added to the repo, when the user commits it? Or will the .gitignore file ignore any new DLL being added, even if the new DLL is named the same as a DLL already being tracked in the Git repo?

Comment: If a file is being tracked already, git will recognize changes to its contents, regardless of whether its in `.gitignore` or not. If you want to stop git from tracking a file, you can stage its removal with `git rm --cached -- <file>` and commit that. (`--cached` will only stage the removal, without physically removing the file from your current working directory)
After that git will ignore changes to that file, because it's no longer tracked.

Comment: Since they're already being tracked, I'll have to issue that `git rm` command you gave for each DLL, PDB, etc. Oh well, thank you, Jay.

Comment: You can pass multiple files to that command at once. And you should be able to get a list of all tracked "ignored" files with `git ls-files -i --exclude-standard`. Might not work with files that ignored because their parent *directories* is in `.gitignore`. At least that's what I gathered from reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320218/how-to-list-files-ignored-by-git-that-are-currently-staged-or-committed

Comment: Also, here an alternative way to do this in git BASH: e.g. `find . -iname '*.dll' -exec git rm --cached {} +` -- will find all *.dll files in the current folder and issue a git rm command for each of them. This way you would have to run only one command per file extension. (The `.` directly after `find` is referring to the current folder you're in. You could replace that dot with `build` or whatever folder/path you want to search)

Comment: I'm kind of curious why this question was closed. What part of the question is not clear and needs to be clarified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository is not your working directory; it's the `.git` directory in your working directory. (These are defaults that can be changed manually, but the idea is the same.)

Just because a file is in your working directory does not mean it is in your repository (such files are called *untracked*). Just because a file is in your repository doesn't mean it is in your working directory. (Such a file may only exist in a branch other than the one you currently have checked out.)

The purpose of `.gitignore` is to cause various commands (`git add`, `git status`, etc) to ignore certain untracked files. You generally only track files that can't be recreated using a build process (`.c` files are tracked, `.o` files that you create on demand by compiling a `.c` file are not). The two main purposes (IMO) of `.gitignore` are

- To avoid accidentally adding a file to your repository with something like `git add .`
- To avoid `git status` from reminding you that the file is untracked.

Specifically, `.gitignore` does *not* apply to changes to files that are already in  your repository. In your example, the DLL files was likely added erroneously. (Git is meant to track *source* files, inputs to your build process. The DLL file is not an input to the build process, but an *output*.)

Comment: Although your answer is correct, I'm not sure it applies to OP's scenario. The (heavily implied) situation in the question is that OP cloned the TFVC repo, and those dlls came along with it, meaning they are in Git now too. (In other words the dlls didn't show up locally because OP tested out a build of something.)

Comment: Then whoever committed them did so by accident or did so before adding them to `.gitignore`. It's not really a question of Git behavior, but of some Git user.

Comment: On second thought, I see what you are saying. `.gitignore` only applies to untracked files, not changes to tracked files (regardless of how that file ended up being tracked). I'll clarify.

Comment: Right, though I don't think it was a Git user, but some TFVC user forgot to add them to the .tfignore file (or similar).

Answer (score 3):

You are correct to worry about this:

> Will rebuilding the app, generating a new File1.dll, mean that new instance of the File1.dll will be added to the repo, when the user commits it?

As mentioned by [Jay in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75761314/id-need-clarification-as-to-how-files-are-ignored-with-the-gitignore-file#comment133646709_75761314), once those files are tracked, the fact that they are in the `.gitignore` file isn't relevant. Those files will continue to show as modified every time someone rebuilds, until they are committed as deleted, or manually told to be untracked in each developer's local repo.

You have a couple of choices here:

1. Make a new commit which deletes all of those files that should never have been tracked to begin with in the TFVC repository.
2. Use [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to go through the entire repo and remove all of the stuff you don't need. Those dlls you found are obvious candidates, but there could potentially be much more than that.

Note that migrating a repo is the *perfect* time to fix it up, since it's much harder to rewrite a Git repo later on without affecting all users of that repo. Besides those build artifacts you already identified, another common fixup is files that were previously added erroneously and later deleted, which are just sitting in the history taking up space for no useful reason. If you decide to try out `git-filter-repo`, start with `git filter-repo --analyze` to see a list of potential candidates to filter out. [More info here.](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html)

**Side Note:** Oftentimes removing unused binaries from the entire history has the additional advantage of significantly reducing the overall size of the repo.

Comment: Reducing the overall size of the repo is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. And not just on the remote, but on developers' machines as well.

Comment: @Rod may I ask why? But sure, in that case you'll probably want option #1. It will solve the problem of tracking those binaries without reducing the size of the repo.