# Inherited bitbucket repo is very large: how to delete a few old commits?

Tags: git, merge, fetch, bitbucket, rebase

I have inherited a project in a Bitbucket repo which is 3.7 GB large. This is the structure with some relevant info to my question:

| Author | Commit | Message | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| me | F | tag v2.1.0 | today |
| ... | E | ... | ... |
| previous | D | tag v1.0.0 | some time ago |
| ... | C | ... | ... |
| ... | B | ... | ... |
| ... | A | ... | ... |

Considering I'm close to the 4GB hard limit, I'd like to know if there's a way to remove all commits besides **D** and **F**. This way our client would have the two functioning versions available, and we would free up the repository of commits that occupy space but aren't used.

I'm thinking of doing it this way, but I have little experience:

1. Pull the **D** commit of the repo (v1.0.0) to a new local folder, separate from where 2.1.0 is.
2. Push from this new local folder with a  *rebase* (not an expert on it). This should "rebase" the remote repo with the current commit, removing everything else (right?). I'd like to use the tag 1.0.0 to keep the naming of the versions that were in place.
3. Fetch this new rebased remote repository from the local 2.1.0 directory.
4. Merge the new changes by only keeping what's in the local (2.1.0) folder and ignoring what comes from the remote one (1.0.0). *How do I do this?*
5. Push from the freshly merged main local folder (where 2.1.0 is) with a `--force-upstream` flag. This should leave it with a 1.0.0 and a 2.1.0 tagged version only

I hope you can help me! Could anyone provide guidance through this seemingly very error-prone process? I am afraid of losing stuff in the process...

Comment: If it is exactly two commits you want to keep, I would personally create a new fresh repo. Copy & paste full sources D into the new repo and create a "initial D commit".  Aferwards, I would checkout F and copy & paste all sources over to create "F commit". Then you delete everything, that is not wanted. I would also keep the original repo as backup just in case.

Very important: 3.7 GB is very large for sources. You must have binary files or images etc. commited which should not be in your in repo. I would figure out what the largest files are, and remove them/save them savewhere else.

Comment: Unless you know that large binaries were added and then deleted prior to `D`, you can't really know how much the commits take up. I'd recommend analyzing your repo with `git-filter-repo`. I think the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75762055/184546) is relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Removing commits may not reduce the repository size as significantly as you expect. You could have a try and find out how much it could get smaller.

```
# create an orphan branch foo from D
git checkout --orphan foo D
git commit -m'commit message'

# create a new commit that tracks the same files with F
git merge $(git commit-tree -p HEAD -m 'commit message' F^{tree})

# create a bundle of foo and check its size
git bundle create foo.bundle foo
du -h foo.bundle
```

If the new repository has only `foo` as the initial branch, you can consider the size of `foo.bundle` as the initial size of the new repository. Compare it with the size of the old repository `.git` (by `du -sh .git`) and you'll get a *rough* estimate of how much it gets smaller.

In some cases, the new size can be almost the same. An example is that from `A` to `F` only new files are added and no files are modified or deleted.

3.7 GB is quite large and it's strongly recommended to use `git lfs` to manage binaries. Otherwise, the new reposiotry will grow huge again after new binaries are tracked.