List all files of specific type that are under version control in git
I have dozens of dozens of (large) git repositories. Clearly, they should be "clean", i.e., do not contain undesired data such as temporary files (say, .aux in case of a LaTeX project, for example). Yet, sometimes these get accidentally added, either by oneself or even authors. To remove them, they should be searched for.
Yet, just searching for these filetypes is not correct, as those files might exist just locally. So, instead, we need to search for files of the respective type that are under version control.
Since I use a global ignore list anyway, i.e., a file listing out all file types that I regard trash (like .aux, but many, many, more), I would like to have a script that:

recursively goes through all subfolders of my current git repo and then lists all such files which are under version control, and
beyond that does the above per git repo, but now also recursively goes through all subfolders (from where I call the script) to also identify all git repositories. (The motivation is that all my git repos are siblings within one folder, so I want to be able to just call that script once in my root).


You do not need that final paragraph stating that this is a self-answered post. That is not part of the question, so don't say it. Just ask the question in the question field,  and answer it in the answer field. Done. Self-answered posts are normal and acceptable. (I have made the edit for you.)

Maybe using a global gitignore is what caused this problem in the first place. If you keep the gitignore file in the repo root and part of the repo, then every repo user will use those ignore properties. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320218/how-to-list-files-ignored-by-git-that-are-currently-staged-or-committed#9370094 for an alternative to your gittrash alias.

I would rather stick to habit of adding proper .gitignore files, and removing of undesired stuff would become trivial - git clean -Xdf

First, I define an alias for the first task (for one single repository):
alias gittrash='xargs -I{} git ls-files "*{}" < "global-gitignore"'

Here, global-gitignore is of course the file containing all patterns (like *.aux), one per line. Given that you want to use this alias from everywhere, you might want to add the absolute file path leading to it.
Now, we can define the function that identifies all git repos. Put this into the same file where you defined the alias (e.g., the zshrc on a Mac).
function gittrashRec {
  # Find all subdirectories that are git repositories
  for repo in $(find . -type d -name ".git" -prune -print | sed 's|/\.git||'); do
    # Navigate to the repository
    cd "$repo"
    
    # Run the gittrash alias command and capture the output
    output=$(gittrash)
    
    # Check if the output is not empty
    if [[ -n "$output" ]]; then
      echo "Repository: $repo"
      echo "$output"
      echo "----------------------------------------"
    fi
    
    # Return to the original directory
    cd - > /dev/null
  done
}

The script only shows the output for git repos that do have one of the undesired files under version control. For it, it also prints the repository (folder) name first. Otherwise, there is no output for the respective repository.

Note that this will not find files under version control but which have been deleted, or which exist in non-checked-out branches.
