# git list ignored cases

Tags: git, github

I have some problems with my git repository, so I don't understand why the .gitignore fails...

it's possible read a list of the .gitignore files and path/files that git ignore?

thanks in advance

Comment: When you say ".gitignore fails", what is your goal? What did you do? What happens?

Comment: I use git for windows, and from the installation, some files under for  example bin\data are ignored, also if the .gitignore from my repository doesn't have some cases like the bin\data...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show ignored files in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the actual files that are currently ignored by your `.gitignore` you can use `git-ls-files`:

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore
```

Comment: This is wrong and can be show to fail in the trivial case: mkdir test && cd test && git init --quiet && echo "str" > fileA && echo "fileA" > .gitignore && git add . && git commit --quiet -a -m "first commit" && git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to have a list of files/folders that git ignores, and obtaining it is as simple as:

```
cat .gitignore
```

Comment: First of all, github is not for Windows, github is a company. In Windows command prompt you can achieve the same by running `type .gitignore`.

Comment: msysgit is your answer. Using it from the command line, you will get way more help.

Comment: Github now has a product called 'Github for Windows': https://github.com/blog/1127-github-for-windows