# Command to view everything Git is ignoring or excluding?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show ignored files in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git)

I have forgotten how I setup my Git, and I would like to know exactly which files it is ignoring. Is there a command, or a list of file I can look through to get reaquainted with my ignore/exclude list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display ignored files in `git status` by using the flag:

```
git status --ignored
```

That'll effectively give you the `git status` as if nothing were being ignored.