# Git default ignore Configure directory

Tags: git

I have push and successively clone a repository with git. I have noticed that git have automatically excluded Configure directory.

Where is this setup? Where I can inform Git to consider that folder too?

Comment: Make sure it was ignored by Git because of "ignore" rule: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you know that it is automatically excluded?

There are a couple of things to look for:

- Have a look in the folder itself for a file called .gitignore. Putting a .gitignore file in a directory is one way to exclude the contents of a directory. It can either list the file patterns to ignore, or a `*` which will exclude everything.
- Have a look in the repository root for the .gitignore file, this will list all the ignores for the repository.
- It's unlikely in your case, but have a look for a file ~/.gitconfig, which may contain a top level entry called [core] with the key `excludesfile` this points to a file which is used as the .gitignore file for all your projects on that system.

For example here is what I have

```
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
```

I wrote about the [three major ways of excluding files in git](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/519016351/three-ways-of-excluding-files) elsewhere.

Comment: Think I resolved. On company's computer there's a sort of custom git client that force some default behaviour. One of this behavior is the exclusion of config directory...

Answer (score 1):

look for a file called `.gitignore`

Comment: There is no local .gitignore in my project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `.gitignore` file in your repo. If you don't have one, look for the `core.excludesfile` value and the file that it points to, to see if Configure directory is ignored. Read here for more info: http://schacon.github.com/git/gitignore.html

Comment: I haven't .gitignore file, that's why I'm going crazy. I don't know why that dir hasn't been tracked :\

Answer (score 1):

I donot think git will exclude your configure directory by default, how did you create your local repository and are you sure directory is not empty? But it should have an .gitignore file to ignore your files, if not look into `core.excludesfile`. Patterns which a user wants git to ignore in all situations (e.g., backup or temporary files generated by the user’s editor of choice) generally go into a file specified by core.excludesfile in the user’s ~/.gitconfig.