# How to list files matched by ignore rules?

Tags: perforce

I have a list of ignore rules in a `p4ignore.txt` per http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/env.P4IGNORE.html

I would like to list the files in my workspace matched by the ignore rules. How can I do that?

(In Git, this is easy https://stackoverflow.com/a/2196755/284795 )

As I understand `p4 status` lists files in the workspace that either

1. exists in the repository (depot) and differ from it
2. don't exist in the repository and *aren't* matched by the ignore rules

I would like to list files in the workspace that are matched by the ignore rules, whether they exist in the repo or not.

Answer (score 3):

If `p4 status` is already returning no files, you can use `p4 reconcile -I` to see what would be added if the ignore rules aren't used.

If `p4 status` is returning files already, but you'd still like to see the difference, you can run it once with and once without `-I` and diff the two.

```
p4 reconcile -n ... > /tmp/foo
p4 reconcile -nI ... > /tmp/foo2
diff /tmp/foo /tmp/foo2
```

Comment: Thanks. Will these list files matched by the rules that also exist in the repository? That's what I'm really interested in—I'm concerned my rules are too wide.

Comment: These will only show things that are not currently in the repository.  `p4 reconcile -n` is the equivalent of `p4 status` and gives you the list of items that are not equivalent in the repository (need to be added, edited, or deleted).   Adding the '-I' just adds in the items that would otherwise be ignored.  Anything up-to-date in the repository won't show up in either list.