# How can I see list of ignored files in git?

Tags: git

I have been using git from past few months and I like git. I was wondering if there is a command which can show list of ignored files in a project.

I tried this `git status --ignored` from root directory of the project but it doesn't seem to be sufficient.

Comment: Why not seem to be sufficient?

Comment: **See Also** [Git command to show which specific files are ignored by .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466764/1366033)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `clean` command with the option:

`-n, --dry-run - Don't actually remove anything, just show what would be done`

```
git clean -ndX
```

In this way git will list all the files that would be cleaned without doing anything, and you get a list of ignored files.

Comment: @SangamGupta you're welcome,. If you find my answer useful please accept it and/or upvote, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. `find -type f  | git check-ignore --stdin` gives all files ignored in whole repo (and if you have some in .git that fit, it will report them too).
2. `git ls-files --exclude-standard --ignored --others` - gives ignored file per current directory (not whole repository).

Both solutions honor not just top-level `.gitignore` file, but also global one, `.git/info/exclude` and local (in lower-level dirs) `.gitignore`s

Comment: Interesting commands. +1

By the way it seems that these two commands don't output the same files, if there are symlinks among ignored paths. But `find -xtype f | git check-ignore --stdin` seems to do the trick.

Comment: An interesting case @ErikMD, thanks for it. `find -type` matches against the file, not symlink so that fits. You may also try `-type l` if you would like to target links specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the .gitignore file found in the same directory as your .git folder if you are looking for a list of files to ignore (listed on each line as regular expressions).

Example:

```
cat .gitignore
```

might show:

```
^build$ 
^build[/].
*-objs/ 
.project
*~
```

Comment: cat .gitignore command will simply display the content of .gitignore file, I am looking for some cleaner way using git command.

Answer (score 0):

use `git check-ignore`, pipe the stdin into it using find.

```bash
find ./ -regex ".*" | git check-ignore --stdin
```