# Clearing all git patches

Tags: git

How do you get rid of untracked patch files in git? I don't understand exactly how to get myself out of this state.
The commands that were run were:

`git format-patch 'some-commit-hash'^..'some-commit-hash'`

`git am *.patch`

And while that didn't exactly do what I was intending, I am stuck with various untracked .patch files. I've tried doing a hard reset to the branch, aborting the format-patch. Swapping to other branches. I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `git reset --hard SHA1` won't remove the untracked files. It will just reset the `HEAD` pointer to the SHA1/commit/branch specified, and **overwrite** the index and the working directory accordingly (changing there only the tracked files).

If you want to "clean up" your working directory in an automatic - but somewhat aggressive way, **beware that the deletion of files cannot be canceled** - a possible solution is to run:

```
git clean -d -x -n
# dry-run to inspect the untracked and ignored files
git clean -d -x -f
# to remove all these files
```

For more information on these commands, you can see e.g. the doc of [git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) as well as the ["Discussion" section of the doc of git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#_discussion).

Another solution if you want more flexibility, is to rely on `git ls-files` to display the list of such files, and possibly chain this with a bash pipe. Below is one such example, which is inspired by [this answer to "How can I see list of ignored files in git?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121129/9164010):

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard --ignored --others | grep '\.patch$'
# to display the ignored or untracked files with .patch file-extension
git ls-files --exclude-standard --ignored --others | grep '\.patch$' | xargs rm -v
# to remove these files
```

Comment: Just a note here. Never use `git clean` unless you really mean it. It will delete files outside of git and there's no going back...

Comment: @Jose indeed: doing `git clean -d -x -f` will delete all untracked files and this action cannot be canceled. I had already mentioned in my answer that `git clean` acts in a "somewhat aggressive way" and recommended to do a dry-run beforehand via `git clean -d -x -n`. But following your comment and to keep on the safe side, I've added an extra comment about this.