# Is there a way to list all excludes for a git repository?

Tags: git

I'd love to get a list of the global excludes and local excludes for my filesystem watcher to ignore

Comment: Do you mean git excludes or contents of .gitignores?

Comment: As i http://stackoverflow.com/a/467053/6309 ?

Comment: @VoC Nope, that lists files in the current repo that are ignored. I want a list of ignore patterns

Comment: @wmorrison365 both? I just want a list of all exclusion patterns being applied to the current repository

Comment: Why don't you just look into the `.gitignore` and the `.git/info/exclude` file?

Comment: @Zeeker Because there is also a global excludesfile and I was wondering if there was a nift git command to just print all the patterns