# rsync betwen repositories the files that git does not track

Tags: git, rsync

Say I have a git directory in `path_A` in a machine `A` with `.gitignore` files all over the place. I have a copy of this repository in a machine in `path_B` in a different machine `B`.

I would like to `rsync` all files from `path_A` to `path_B` that are not tracked by git so that both machines have effectively the same files (e.g. including binaries). Is there a relatively simple way of doing this?

Comment: http://getidephix.com/?

Answer (score 1):

You can give 2 arguments to rsync - first exclude all files: `--exclude="*"` then use include-from with the .gitignore file as argument: `--include-from='.gitignore'`

The first exclusion makes rsync ignore all by default. The latter inclusion reads include patterns from a file called .gitignore, which leads to all gitignored files being included in the rsync.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I have multiple `.gitignore` files under my repository (in different folders), so I guess there is more work to do. I wonder if there is a way to have `git` dump to disk the list of files that it doesn't track and somehow feed that to rsync.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/467053/1615903 has information about listing the ignored files. In short: `git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard`