# Using git ignore data to list files currently in working tree

Tags: git

Context: I'm using a static checker to verify files in my working tree.
I want to check all files in the current directory except those that *would* be ignored by git (object files for instance), including those that were not yet added to the repository. I also want to exclude files that are known to git but were deleted locally.

I think the best way to achieve that would be by using

```
find . -type f -exec <some git command that filters the input with git ignore>
```

...or by using `git-ls` with some option, or by using `git show --porcelain`

Comment: Oddly enough, the "Related" section on this page has [Show ignored files in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git?rq=1) which tells how you can get a list of ignored files. That should get you what you want.

Comment: I need a list of files that *would not be ignored*, and not a list of ignored files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD
```