# Does directory name case matter while ignoring a directory in Git on windows?

Tags: windows, git

Does directory name case matters while ignoring a directory in Git on windows?

Say if  `bin/` and `Bin/` are same in exclude file in git on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested it with [Git for Windows 1.9.5](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/) (not [yet tested with Git for Windows 2.3.5](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) though)

It doesn't seem to be case sensitive: `bin/xxx` and `Bin/xxx` are equally ignored when `bin/` or `Bin/` are set in the `.gitignore` on Windows.

Ie, [`git check-ignore -v bin/xxx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/467053/6309) would return `Bin/` rule if `Bin/` was in `.gitignore`.