# github is not the same after push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm wondering how this is possible.
I made quite a bit of changes to my rails project (deleted some stuff, edited files, added files, ...) as I implemented a whole new design. 
And now I want to commit my project and push it to github

```
git merge new-view
git add .
git commit -am "implemented the new design"
git push origin master
```

Now when I pulled the changes on another computer I noticed that not all of my features were working. (for example the image slider wasn't functioning).
When I go trough the files, it looks like all the changes I made are there, but I must be missing something because both projects are not behaving in the same way!
Even when I clone the project again from github (**on the original computer with the working projectfolder**), the feature still doesn't work.

```
git clone projectname
```

Now in my old folder I can't push any other changes as status tells me that my branch is up to date with origin/master

```
git status
```

I figure that I can just delete the github project and upload it again, but that's obviously not the way this is supposed to be done.
Any ideas what could've gone wrong?

Comment: why do you have `git add .` after merge? were there conflicts?

Comment: If the files you pulled are correct, it cannot be related to git. Are you sure your browser didn't cache old files?

Comment: do you Ignore some important files in .gitignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that no important files are being ignored- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git)

Make sure everything is truly committed.  `git status` and `git status --cached`

Make sure any databases are initialized, migrated and populated with the same data.

Check browser caching.

Comment: it must have been some browser caching, because in incognito mode they all behave in the same way (faulty). So I need to solve another problem, git was doing its job as it was supposed to.

Thank you all for the answers