# How to find a complete list of untracked (and non-ignored) files within a git repository?

Tags: git, gitignore

Under a specific ***`<directory>`*** (within a git repository),
I want a complete list of files that are:

- untracked by git
- but **not** ignored by git (using `.gitignore`).

Is there an easy way to do this?

*Note that while `git status` does list untracked files that are **not** ignored,

it fails to list the actual files within any untracked sub-directories within the git repository.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show ignored files in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git)

Comment: This is not a duplicate since that question asked to show ignored files and this to show **non**-ignored files (that are untracked).

Comment: Hmmm... ok. Misread the Q. Retracted the my duplicate close-vote. What threw me off was that this question initially appeared to be a misconstrued example that was answered by yourself immediately. **My apologies for not properly reading it the first time**. Added  a few details; hopefully it clarifies the Q & A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by using `git ls-files`.

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard [directory]
```

- **-o** shows other (i.e. untracked) files in the output
- **--exclude-standard** adds the standard Git exclusions
  from `.gitignore` in each directory, `.git/info/exclude` and `~/.gitignore_global`.

---

Here is a sample git repository with 2 new untracked local files. Both of which are in a newly added untracked directory. One of the untracked files matches a pattern `*.o` specified in the `.gitignore`.

```
~/linux-stable$ ls -lR kernel/untracked-dir/
kernel/untracked-dir/:
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cvs cvs 7 Sep  2 18:46 untracked-ignored-file.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cvs cvs 7 Sep  2 18:46 untracked-non-ignored-file.c
```

Running `git status`simply lists the new untracked sub-directory  and not the individual files within

```
~/linux-stable$ git status kernel/
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

kernel/untracked-dir/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

> Whereas using **`git ls-files -o --exclude-standard`**, we get :
>
> ```
> ~/linux-stable$ git ls-files -o --exclude-standard 
> kernel/untracked-dir/untracked-non-ignored-file.c
> ```
>
> **i.e. the actual list of untracked-files (including the ones within any untracked directories).**

Comment: Looks like you posted a question and its answer almost simultaneously. If you are interested in documenting stuff on StackOverflow, consider joining the [**Documentation Beta**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow).

Comment: I thought answering your own question was a behavior that was encouraged. I still think this is suitable for the QA format of stackoverflow. In addition it's not that clear how I find that "Documentation".

Comment: No offense intented, as detailed in the SO meta question linked in my previous comment above, register for the public beta of [StackOverflow Documentation](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13ynCK-DEy0osod8VIENajnbFJNZxXm1jyeupBrl5v44/viewform). It aims to be the "next big thing" to submit/maintain such useful bits of clarity to otherwise obscure code/commands.

Comment: I don't like the idea to register if I can't see what I'm registering to before. Fx I registered to stackoverflow because that was were I ended up when I search for answers to my questions and I found answers here before I registered.