# What exclude pattern should i specify

Tags: git

I want to understand the exclude pattern in git ls-files command. 
So I want to output all the ignored file within the working directory using the `ls-files` command. I know that `git status --ignored` will do the job, but my point is to understand using the exclude pattern in case I need it.

I tried this: `git ls-files -i -x ./*.txt`
In order to output all the ignored (except text-files) files. No success though I have several ignored files.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `git ls-files -o -i -x '*.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

A simple StackOverflow search would have answered your question.

Try any of these:

```
git ls-files --others -i --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard
```

Reference: [Git command to show which specific files are ignored by .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git)