# how to remove text output from git clean -n output (short Q)

Tags: git, macos, unix

given problem: list all the existing files ignored by your Git repository to an .sh file

stuck at: how to remove the "would remove part so I can move them to .sh file

My solution:

when I input:

```
git clean -n
```

I get:

```
Would remove .DS_Store

Would remove ex02/.DS_Store
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git command to show which specific files are ignored by .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+ignored+files