# File disappears when I unstage, why?

Tags: git

I have a file that was deleted in a previous commit so I did the following:

```
git checkout e441c9b~1 <myfile>
```

Then the file was back in the staging area. Out of curiosity I did

```
git reset HEAD <myfile>
```

and the file disappeared, where I would have expected that the file would just stay in my repo untracked.

Actually if I go to the folder the file is there, but `git status` says nothing about it, I am confused. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Is the file shown with `git status --ignored`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes it is shows as ignored but i don't understand why.

Comment: Because it's in a `.gitignore` file somewhere.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore

Comment: That was it, for some reason the files were added before the `.gitignore` was made.