# single command to find all git ignored files and why they are being ignored

Tags: git

I can find out what files are being ignored with

```
git status --ignored
```

I can find out why *one* file is being ignored with

```
git check-ignore -v somefile
```

How to combine the two? My feeble attempts don't work. Expressions like

```
git check-ignore -v .
```

or

```
get check-ignore -v **/*
```

come up way short; they list only a tiny fraction of the files listed in `git status --ignored`. (For example, `.DS_Store` files don't appear at all.)

The best I could come up with, with my feeble unix fu, is:

```
git status --ignored | tr -d '\t' | git check-ignore --verbose --stdin
```

But it errors out on the final empty line of the `status` output, and it seems nutty that I have to play these pipe games at all.

Comment: There're many variants at https://stackoverflow.com/a/467053/7976758 (found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+all+ignored+files). For example `find . -type f -exec git check-ignore -v '{}' \+` or `git check-ignore -v $(find . -type f)` or `git check-ignore -v $(git ls-files --others)`

Comment: You don't need the quotes, `find -type f -exec git check-ignore -v {} +`.

Comment: @phd I particularly like `git check-ignore -v $(find . -type f -print)` although I don't see how to exclude the `.git` folder as suggested by the comments. I still find it very bizarre there isn't just a direct git command.

Comment: @jthill: some shells (csh/tcsh in particular) will eat the braces if they are not quoted.

Comment: @matt: `find . -name .git -prune -o -type f -print` does the trick.

Comment: @torek good and fair point, I've come to feel curmudgeonly about it tho, if people want to use oddbal shells I'm not gonna uglify my world to cater to them, they can keep their  limitations and adapt the common syntax for themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swiss-army-knife of git aware file listing is `git ls-files`.

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -oi
```

will list all unindexed ignored files.  And `git check-ignore` has a `--stdin` option, so...

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -oi | git check-ignore -vn --stdin
```

does what you want, about as fast as possible.  I want that `--exclude-standard` option often enough that I have a global alias for it, `git config --global alias.ls "ls-files --exclude-standard"`, so for me it'd be `git ls -oi | git check-ignore -vn --stdin`.

Comment: Yup, I like that best, thanks. Still don't quite see why no single git command just _does_ this.

Comment: I'd say because it's easily constructible with two existing git commands, each of them useful without the other.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash 4+:

Enable `globstar` and `dotglob`:

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s dotglob
```

and:

```
git check-ignore -v **/*
```

In `zsh` globstar (known as *recursive globbing*) is on by default so just enable `dotglob`:

```
setopt dotglob
```

and:

```
git check-ignore -v **/*
```

Comment: The problem with `**/*` (as it's demonstrated in the question) is it skips dot-files (`.*`).