# Git - Can't Add Files - No Git Ingore and Git info/exclude doesnt have them in it

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku

I am having trouble getting the build file of my react website added to GIT. I am trying to push it to heroku... and in the past, git has included the build file.

I have checked to make sure there is no .git ignore file and made sure the exclude file doesn't include the build folder.

Any suggestions on where to look next?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git command to show which specific files are ignored by .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore)

Comment: Why do you want to track build artifacts? Let _Heroku_ build your application. Don't track generated files.

Comment: Oh - I didnt know that heroku would do the build process for me on a react app?

Comment: It seems if I dont run the build before I deploy then nothing works. xxxx.herokuapp.com says 'Not Found'