# git status showing untracked files although ignored

Tags: git

I have some entries in my `.gitignore` file in my `git` repository but some of the entries still show up as untracked files.

The important parts from my `.gitignore` file:

```
# IDE settings
.idea/

# Environments
win_venv/

# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/

# Distribution / packaging
*.egg-info/
```

However, when I run `git status`, this shows up:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .idea/
        mypackage.egg-info/
        mypackage/__pycache__/
        mypackage/schema/__pycache__/
        mypackage/schema/models/__pycache__/
        mypackage/tests/__pycache__/
        win_venv/
```

Anyone knows, why this can happen or what the mistakes in my `.gitignore` file are?

This question is different to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) suggested, as shown files are not tracked. This issue also happens, if I create a new virtual environment `venv`, having the appropriate entry in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: They have probably been added despite being in the ignore file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: But is it possible they show up as "Untracked files" then?

Comment: What os are you running ?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but where is your `.gitignore` located?

Comment: It's at the top level project folder beside the `.git` folder.

Comment: Please show the whole gitignore file as well as any other files in play such as global gitignore.

Comment: @AnsFourtyTwo: "I'm on Windows 10." ok. Also : is your git folder located on a regular folder/partition ? or is it in a "special folder" (shared folder for onedrive or dropbox, a network filesystem ...) ?

Comment: It is in a regular NTFS filesystem folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a tricky one and another proof, that `git` works better on Linux. The problem in this very specific case was, that the file encoding was not properly set, so the `.gitignore` file was handled as a binary file.

Thank you @LeGEC for pointing me into the right direction: I figured out, that something is wicked, when I did a `cat .gitignore` on a WSL console and the content looked something like this:

```
    I D E   s e t t i n g s
 . i d e a /

 #   B y t e - c o m p i l e d   /   o p t i m i z e d   /   D L L   f i l e s
 _ _ p y c a c h e _ _ /
```

Comment: As you discovered, Git does not understand Windows UTF-16 encodings. (This is true for other files as well—UTF-16 encodings will result in Git thinking they are binary...)

Comment: (facepalm) nice catch @AnsFourtyTwo

Answer (score 2):

(not an answer, just a list of suggestions to further debug the issue)

Try running `git status` from different shells : `cmd.exe`, `powershell`, `git-bash` and see if the behavior is the same in all three.

You can also see more information with the following commands :

```
git status --ignored

git check-ignore -v [paths]
# 'check-ignore' only checks paths explicitly listed on the command line :
git check-ignore -v *
git check-ignore -v .idea mypackage.egg-info mypackage/__pycache__
```

more details in this question : [Git command to show which specific files are ignored by .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore)

Finally : you can also run `git add .idea/` (perhaps choose the folder with the least files ?) and see what gets added.
You can revert that using `git reset .idea/`

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the current `.gitignore` file and then create it as a txt file then rename it to `.gitignore`. This happens in windows only

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you add files/folders to .gitignore then these files/folders will still be present in your repository index.

Follow steps to get rid of it:

**Step 1** . First committed all your changes, including your .gitignore file

**Step 2**. Remove or clear your repo, use below command including dot [.]

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Your repository is clean and git status should not show untracked file now

> The . indicates that all files will be untracked

> --cached will only remove files from the index

**Step 3**. Re add everything & commit

```
 git commit -a -m ".gitignore fix"
```

Your repository is clean and git status should not show untracked folders

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, actually this is not the problem in my case. Files were definitely not added and therefore shown as untracked files.