# How to git add back the file to a repo which accidentally ignored by source tree previously

Tags: git

I previously use Sourcetree to ignore the file index.jsx by accidentally. So right now, each time I created a index.jsx in different folder/path, it will be ignored automatically, unless I git add manually in IDE. So is there anyway that I can git add back index.jsx?

Comment: Are you asking about git or a particular IDE? If git, have you tried removing it from `.gitignore`?

Comment: I am not familiar with Sourcetree. There should be a `.gitignore` file in the project. It's a plain-text file. You can remove the entry for index.jsx from that file (and commit it).

Comment: I have checked .gitignore file in IDE, but index.jsx file was not in there.

Comment: To debug a git ignore issue: run `git check-ignore -v <path/to/file>`. If a file is ignored, you will see a detailed list of the rules that target this file, and where the gitignore file is located.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git command to show which specific files are ignored by .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers. just found out how to solve this situation;

I used the MacOS, SourceTree, RunbyMine at same time. When you ignore a file in SourceTree, SourceTree usually will put this file's name and extension(like index.jsx) into the .gitignore_global. You can go to setting -> git ->Global ignore List -> edit file to remove it.